# MDX and DAX Measure produce non-exist value

Tags: ssas, mdx, dax

I'm studying Tabular model in SQL Server 2012 Analysis service.

I made a cube like this.
[image]

First of all, I checked my data and the result as follows
(sorry, where statement is meaningless)
[image]

PCs on Contract Measure define like this =>
PCs on Contract:=SUM([PC Count])

However, when I made a chart in a performance point(Sharepoint)
, the result shows terrible. so I checked the MDX query used by the chart.

This is the MDX Query and the result.
[image]

In fact table, ServiceContractID values are all exist ContractID value in the ServiceContract.

I'm really hard to understand why there is empty value. What cause this wrong calculation?
(When I made this using a Multi-dimensional for test, I can get a result which I expected.)

Comment: Have you tried filtering down the dataset further to find individual contracts with discrepancies and then looking them up in your underlying tabular model? Perhaps a relationship issue, or a data trunc and load issue, processing, the only way to determine it is to dig down to a row and then figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Also I'd recommend simplifying your fact table query to a much smaller dataset of say, 10 rows while testing so you can quickly drill in.

Answer (score 0):

When you checked your data with SQL queries, you used `WHERE DateKey = 20121231` but your MDX has no such restriction on dates.

Either you run your SQL again without the WHERE and see if you see some extra rows, or you add a date filter to the MDX.

Comment: Mate I wrote it where statement is meaningless, because there are only data that the DataKey is 20121231. Without this fact, the third and forth query shows all ServiceContractID in Fact table are in the ServiceContract Dimension table. Therefore, the result is totally wrong with empty contract level.

Comment: OK, as long as you are sure! I have made assumptions like this before, then found a few rogue rows of data have crept in where I expected none.